# How to pass variable parameter for "IN clause"

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, datastax

I am preparing a session.execute statement as below. 
I have few conditions and one IN clause. I am getting the below error. 
I know I am doing a mistake but not able to make it work.
`filter_site_value = ['filter 1', 'filter 2']`

```
session = get_session()
query = 'SELECT * FROM table where cv = %s AND dt > %s and dt < %s AND st IN  (%s)' % ','.join('%s' for i in filter_site_value)
data = (filter_customer_value,filter_date_start_value, filter_date_end_value, filter_site_value)
rows = session.execute(query, data)
```

"errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "not enough arguments for format string"

Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `','.join('%s' %i for i in filter_site_value)`?

Comment: not even able to form basic query using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your string has 3 places where it needs to format a value into it (`%s`), you only provide one value: `','.join('%s' for i in filter_site_value)`

So if you have:

```
x = string_to_format % values
```

and string_to_format contains X amount of `%s` (or `%d %r ...`) then you need X values in `values`

see:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html , https://pyformat.info/

What you probably want to do is:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table where cv = %s AND dt > %s and dt < %s AND st IN  ('+ ','.join(filter_site_value)+')'
data = (filter_customer_value,filter_date_start_value, filter_date_end_value)
```

or

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table where cv = %s AND dt > %s and dt < %s AND st IN  ('+ ','.join(%s for i in filter_site_value)+')'
data = (filter_customer_value,filter_date_start_value, filter_date_end_value)+tuple(filter_site_value)
```